# Active Class Dropdown Menu in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my side navigation code

i want to make the dropdown item 1 active

i try to remove `class="collapse"` at `ul` and the menu success to show the dropdown items, but the problem is how to highlight the menu dropdown item 1?

i add `class='active'` to the li tag, but it's not work

what is the class to make it highlight as active menu?

```
<li>
    <a href="bootstrap-grid.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i> Bootstrap Grid</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> Dropdown <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
        <li class='active'>
            <a href="#">Dropdown Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Dropdown Item 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="blank-page.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i> Blank Page</a>
</li>
```

Comment: `i add class='active' to the li tag, but it's not work` what is not working?

Comment: the menu background color not changing, if li at dashboard i give active class, then the menu color change

Answer (score 0):

As you are already assigning `active` class to `li` tag, so now you just need to make sure that you have proper CSS classes available in your CSS file.

**Update:**

```
.active {
  color: #FC0 !important;
}
```

Comment: the css come from bootstrap, when i gave active class to dashboard, the color changed, but whe i try give to child dropdown, color not change

Comment: if this is the case then it should work, But try adding `!important` to you css code where code for active class is available. check the update section in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can style an li with active in the way you're thinking, but you can do it with css.

```
.active {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```